# Javascript loop countdown timer

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

```js
function timer()

{
 var currentTime = new Date()
 var hours = currentTime.getHours()
 var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
 var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

 if (minutes < 10)
 {
  minutes = "0" + minutes
 }
 
 if (hours < 6)
 {
  var hoursLeft = 5 – hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 – minutes;
  
  if(minsLeft==60)
  {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }
 var secsLeft = 60 – seconds;
 
  if(secsLeft==60)
  {
   secsLeft=0;
   minsLeft++;
  }
 }

 else if (hours < 18)
 {
  var hoursLeft = 17 – hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 – minutes;
  
  if(minsLeft==60)
  {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }

  var secsLeft = 60 – seconds;
  
  if(secsLeft==60)
  {
   secsLeft=0;
      minsLeft++;
  }
 }
 
 else if (hours < 24)
 {
  var hoursLeft = 29 – hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 – minutes;
  
  if(minsLeft==60)
  {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }
  
  var secsLeft = 60 – seconds;
  
  if(secsLeft==60)
  {
   secsLeft=0;
   minsLeft++;
  }
 }
 
 else if (hours == 6)
 {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("reset.html", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
 
 else if (hours == 18)
 {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("reset.html", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
 
 else
 {
  document.write("Error, please contact admin");
 }

 document.getElementById('timerUpFront').innerHTML= hoursLeft + " hours " + minsLeft + " minutes " + secsLeft + " seconds";
}

 var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```css
#timerUpFront
{
 color:#009DE3;
}

#timer
{
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size:36px;
  text-align:center;
}

#button
{
 background-color:#008CFF;
 font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size:26px;
 width:160px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 2em auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="timer">
<span id="timerUpFront"></span>
<br><br>
<div id="button">
<center><a href="reset.html" style="text-decoration:none">Reset</a></center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to create an automated countdown timer that should reset it self back to once reach 0:00:00 or once the button is pressed but does not reset on page refresh.
I have been trying for hours but couldn't get the timer to display, couldn't find any mistake in .js file my self to display. As my last option had to ask on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if someone pranked you or something, but you're using a bigger dash character (I'm not sure what that's called), instead of a regular minus sign. I replaced `–` with `-`.

```js
function timer()

{
 var currentTime = new Date()
 var hours = currentTime.getHours()
 var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
 var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

 if (minutes < 10)
 {
  minutes = "0" + minutes
 }
 
 if (hours < 6)
 {
  var hoursLeft = 5 - hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
  
  if(minsLeft==60)
  {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }
 var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;
 
  if(secsLeft==60)
  {
   secsLeft=0;
   minsLeft++;
  }
 }

 else if (hours < 18)
 {
  var hoursLeft = 17 - hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
  
  if(minsLeft==60)
  {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }

  var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;
  
  if(secsLeft==60)
  {
   secsLeft=0;
      minsLeft++;
  }
 }
 
 else if (hours < 24)
 {
  var hoursLeft = 29 - hours;
  var minsLeft = 60 - minutes;
  
  if(minsLeft==60)
  {
   minsLeft=0;
   hoursLeft++;
  }
  
  var secsLeft = 60 - seconds;
  
  if(secsLeft==60)
  {
   secsLeft=0;
   minsLeft++;
  }
 }
 
 else if (hours == 6)
 {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("reset.html", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
 
 else if (hours == 18)
 {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("reset.html", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }
 
 else
 {
  document.write("Error, please contact admin");
 }

 document.getElementById('timerUpFront').innerHTML= hoursLeft + " hours " + minsLeft + " minutes " + secsLeft + " seconds";
}

 var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```css
#timerUpFront
{
 color:#009DE3;
}

#timer
{
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size:36px;
  text-align:center;
}

#button
{
 background-color:#008CFF;
 font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size:26px;
 width:160px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 2em auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="timer">
<span id="timerUpFront"></span>
<br><br>
<div id="button">
<center><a href="reset.html" style="text-decoration:none">Reset</a></center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```